# Fluidmaster not working rubbing up against plastic flush flow box

Tags: plumbing

Fluidmaster is rubbing up against the plastic flush flow plastic box.  How to fix a dig still keep running.  I need to get away from the box any suggestions

Comment: Could you add a picture? And make sure to describe what part of the picture has the area that rubs?

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. Please take a moment to reread your post as though you were one of us who have no idea what your situation is. You may note that some things (like "How to fix a dig still keep running") don't make much sense unless we already know what you're talking about. Please feel free to [edit] your question to add additional detail and clarity, plus some pictures, as izzy asked. That will make it _much_ easier for us to help you out. Once you've done that, take the [tour] to see how this site works - it'll help pass a minute while you're waiting for an answer or two.

Comment: what exactly us rubbing? ... fluidmaster is a brand name ... it is not a specific device

Comment: Like this? https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/221895/18078 Please [edit] to clarify your question and add a picture.