Removing toilet tank dam
I understand that this plastic container was added to conserve water, but it's not saving water because we have to flush the toilet 2 to 3 times anyways to get anything to go down. The toilet is small and on the 3rd floor. How do I go about removing the plastic container?

See: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/221911/18078 Go buy a modern, properly designed toilet that actually flushes in one flush without needing 5 gallons, disconnect the toilet from the flange and the waterline, install new toilet, save water and flush in one.

It looks like that plastic thing has a round hole in it that is fitted under the seal of the water tank trap where it is positioned over the top of the stool. The normal removal procedure would be to remove the bolts that hold the tank to the stool and then remove the tank trap. (Doing this would also entail disconnecting the fill valve assembly from the water supply line so that the tank can be lifted away from the stool). When doing the tank trap unit it would be a wise decision to get new parts to replace the old seals and parts and maybe even a new set of tank to stool bolts and seals.
An alternate solution that may be a lot simpler may be to simply cut the plastic thing inside the tank out down to its base leaving the base in place. In fact it may even be sufficient to just remove one or two sides of the plastic thing!

I see no other attachment points in the picture, so it looks like you will need to remove the tank. Then remove the big nut holding the flush valve seat to the tank. You should then be able to remove the dam.
OR
Cut down the sides of the dam and across the bottom to remove the sections. This may be able to be cut with heavy scissors or snips.
Possibly you could drill some big holes in the sides.
You just need to defeat the purpose of holding back water. The entire part does not need to be removed.
